# How to develop a menu where the current route remains laterally to the menu

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to developing apps flutter, but I want to develop a menu where the current tab is sample within the menu itself, I do not know how to explain, and if it is possible, but could not find a similar tutorial and do not know if there is any specific name for this type of menu, could someone help me with this?

It would be something in the style of this design ... but in my case just show the current page there, is possible in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/hidden_drawer_menu 
github https://github.com/RafaelBarbosatec/hidden_drawer_menu 
full example code https://github.com/RafaelBarbosatec/hidden_drawer_menu/tree/master/example

or https://pub.dev/packages/kf_drawer 
github https://github.com/qqmikey/kf_drawer

hidden_drawer_menu

[image]

kf_drawer

[image]